# Как привязать функцию добавления товара в корзину на woocommerce к своей сверстанной кнопке?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

У меня есть карточки товаров на woocommerce. В них есть кнопка, добавляющая этот товар в корзину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я на главной сверстала карточку товара+кнопку версткой, мне нужно, чтобы эта кнопка добавляла этот товар в корзину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, реально ли это реализовать и каким образом это можно сделать? Может, где-то можно прочитать про это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если товар простой то смотрите как выводится кнопка в цикле у простых товаров. Айди товара подставляете свой.

```
<a href="?add-to-cart=101" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="101">В корзину</a>
```